# How to activate an action after another action happens

Tags: animation, scripting, game-engine

I made a camera action using Blender Game engine and set it to run at the beginning of the game now I want to activate another action after this action is done

Answer (score 1):

In the Action Actuator you can set a property which reflects the current action frame. You can then check its value and start the second action when the end frame of the first one is reached.

[image: Logic Bricks Setup]